# Removing clickonce app remnants, it tries to re-install every login

Tags: .net, clickonce

We have a client prompted our app installation after every computer log-in. My thinking they uninstalled the app while its still running(which I thought it messed the regedit) and re-installed. I did 3 days research but I am still with no solution. Also I searched but couldn't find a good answer how to prevent user uninstalling the app without closing the app?

Here below, what I have tried so far:

- Uninstall what can be uninstalled from Add and Remove Control Panel applet.
- Executed rundll32 C:\Windows\system32\dfshim.dll CleanOnlineAppCache
- Executed mage.exe -cc
- Deleted all content from %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0.
- Deleted shortcuts still found in the Start Menu, by opening %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs...